# SVG image - fixed height - keep ratio - slice

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG that needs to have a fixed height so its not super big when the width is 2000+ pixels (widescreens...)
The clipping mask should always be visible and the background image should be sliced and not be stretchend, i tried several things but nothing seems to work.

This is what i have now:
https://codepen.io/bucky208/pen/OEqbPp

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1024 1381.5" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 100%;height: 400px;">
        <g id="clipgroup">
          <defs>
            <polygon id="mask" points="0,572.1 0,1381.3 1024,1040.5 1024,337.6 0,0"/>
          </defs>
          <clipPath id="mask_1_">
            <use xlink:href="#mask"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
          </clipPath>
          <g style="clip-path:url(#mask_1_);">
              <image style="overflow:visible;" width="331" height="444" id="theimage" xlink:href="https://image.ibb.co/ipbNkJ/56_E0406_E5_C8_EF897.jpg"  transform="matrix(3.1119 0 0 3.1111 -3.0528 -2.604167e-04)"></image>
          </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Do i need another wrapper around everything? How do i restore the image ratio?

Kind regards and a big thank you for everyone trying to help.

Comment: Your code snippet has two opening `<svg>` tags, but only one closing. Is the nested svg indended?

Comment: For the last few minutes I've been trying to figure out what you want to achieve, but frankly, I can't. Please edit your question and try to describe seperately: What part of the image (before clipping) should be visible for different screen sizes? What dimension should the clip path have for different screen sizes? Should the clip path always clip out the same part of the image?

Comment: my bad, changed it. Michael has what i'm looking for i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get image fills to fill their container but preserve the original aspect ratio, a filter combined with objectBoundingBox sizing and preserveAspectRatio is your friend. The following code does what I think you want:

```css
svg {
  background: red;
}

#svgcont {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="svgcont">
     <svg  x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="800px">

          <defs>
            <filter id="image-fill-nostretch" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feImage x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="theimage" xlink:href="https://image.ibb.co/ipbNkJ/56_E0406_E5_C8_EF897.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
              <feComposite operator="in" x1="SourceGraphic"/>
            </filter>
            
          <clipPath id="mask_1_" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
               <polygon id="mask" points="0,0.5 0,1 1,0.75 1,0.25 0,0"/>
          </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <g clip-path="url(#mask_1_)">
              <rect width="100%"height="100%" x="0%" y="0%" filter="url(#image-fill-nostretch)"/>
          </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```